# error after updating PHP version in Wampserver 3.2.0 : syntax error in httpd.conf

Tags: php, wampserver, httpd.conf

I update the php version in wamp to php8.1.8 but the wampserver icon is orange and says `2 of 3 services running`

and the error is in the picture [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o60qf.png)

and [the picture of where the error is](https://i.stack.imgur.com/swa9o.png)

I don't know if there is a way to share my httpd.conf with you ...

any help?

Comment: I think there's no way to share whole file :(

Comment: Use paste bin to do that